# Input field in IE 10 does not recognize required and placeholder attribute via ip address but via localhost it works

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer-10

Here is my form:

```
<form action="Validation2" method="post">
        <p><label for="username">Username: </label>
        <input class="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required/></p>
        <p><label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input class="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="********" required/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="send"></p>

    </form>
```

and my Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If i access the website under localhost it works fine, but if access the website under the IP address there is no placeholder and the required attribute does not work.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Check if you have the compatibility mode with your IP

Comment: @Fabio, compatibility mode (Quirks Mode) may depend on IP but does not cause issues like this.

Comment: The odds are that the web server sends the document with somewhat different content. You need to show an actual example of a complete HTML document (preferably minimal) that causes this problem. It is possible to put IE to e.g. IE 9 emulation mode, where many HTML5 novelties are disabled, but this requires a user action and does not depend on local vs. server access.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I have solved the problem with this line.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```